Coldfusion Scheduled task with Async function
I have an issue that I can't figure out online to resolve.
I am using CF 2021 (Update 8) and I have my main.cfm file which will make a call to my database using Ajax (have a service.cfc file with the query), once data is retrieved from the DB, I render it on the UI and then call another function within the service.cfc file to email the UI content. This works perfectly in my browser so I assumed I could just create a scheduled task to execute main.cfm hourly and an email would be created... Boy was I wrong.
I know for a fact that email works and scheduling tasks are good as I have removed all logic in the main.cfm with just mail task and I do get the empty email.
My thought process its an async problem, so I set the Ajax async field to false but this didn't help. Any idea of a fix for this?

What's the point of running AJAX when the scheduled task is run on the server anyway?

@mykaf I wanted to have a MVC design pattern where logic would be split between different files. So the Ajax call to the service.cfc has logic I could use else where if needed.

Ajax calls will not work on scheduled task as the request is not run using a browser. Schedule tasks runs the provided URL in a similar way how Postman runs requests.

You should still be able to use the logic in service.cfc, but you'd need to call it with a "traditional" function call.

@rrk dam I didn't know schedule task behavior in this manner :( Is there any workaround possible? I have done a lot of development and have a working solution to have to rework everything. Just wondering...

Whatever cfm page you have in your task scheduler now, just update it to call the function however you normally would, such as using <cfinvoke> or service().method().

@mykaf, I don't follow your recommendation.. so my pattern in main.cfm (which is executed with CF schedule task) is using $.get('service.cfc?method=updateDescription&value=someValue');  where service.cfc consist of something like this:  <cfcomponent>   <cffunction name="updateDescription" access="remote" returntype="string">     <cfargument name="value" type="string" required="yes">     <cftry>       your code here     <cfcatch>       <cfoutput>       </cfoutput>     </cfcatch>     </cftry>   </cffunction> </cfcomponent>

So replace $.get('service.cfc?method=updateDescription&value=someValue'); with <cfinvoke component="service" method="updateDescription" value="someValue"></cfinvoke>

@mykaf, I am using a similar $.get to send email (html value) from the first call which I pass in the body. I don’t think I can achieve this using cfinvoke based on what I have read. Really hoping there is an easy workaround instead of rewriting

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
